# cURL to install theme

Tags: api, wp-cli, installation

I can't figure for the head of mine how to write a cURL that would install a theme for me once I got a session.

Tried binding these headers, but with no success:

```
_wpnonce
_wp_http_refferer
_themezip + filename
```

Any ideas?